# Building an object list with Linq to Xml

Tags: xml, linq

I am trying to extract values from an XML file using linq to create a list of objects.  The XML File looks like this.

```
<RootNode>
  <Node1>
     <Node2>
        <results>
           <work>
              <title>title1</title>
              <author>author</author>
              <image_url>image</image_url>
            </work>
    ...
</RootNode>

XDocument results = XDocument.Load("url");
```

There can be multiple occurrences of these 'work' nodes (and subsequent child nodes) depending on the search.  For each occurrence of 'work' I want to extract the title/author/image values to build a simple book object:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Now I can iterate through the xml file and pick out indivual values using something like this:

```
foreach (XElement element in results.Descendants("title"))
{
    string title = element.Value;
}
```

but as I want to build a list of books I have been trying various things much like this:

```
List<Book> books = 
    (from book in results.Descendants("work")
            select new Book
            {
                Title = book.Element("title").Value,
                Author = book.Element("name").Value,
                ImageUrl = book.Element("image_url").Value,
            }).ToList<Book>();
```

However I keep getting a null reference exceptionfor this.  Any pointers of where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Kevin.

**EDIT**

Hi guys turns out the problem was with the XML file and not the linq statement.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me after several minor modifications:

```
    var books = (from book in results.Descendants("work")
        select new Book
                {
                    Title = book.Element("title").Value,
                    Author = book.Element("author").Value,
                    ImageUrl = book.Element("image").Value,
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  Yes what I have looks correct to me however I keep gettin this null reference exception was unhandled by user.  Its very strange as I can pick out a single element fine as demonstrated in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

By null value do you mean null reference exception? I see that in your code your are looking for a "image_url" element but in your sample there is an "image" element.